# How can I find next higher number based on certain where-conditions?

Tags: sql

I have to find the next higher sequence-number depending on certain where-conditions:

TABLE:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------------------+
|  Seq  |    Start_Time    |           Queue           |
+-------+------------------+---------------------------+
| 34962 | 28.07.2020 17:06 | PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM |
| 35393 | 29.07.2020 11:03 |                           |
| 35394 | 29.07.2020 11:03 |                           |
| 42886 | 04.09.2020 14:16 | PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM |
| 42887 | 04.09.2020 14:16 | PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM |
| 42888 | 04.09.2020 14:16 |                           |
| 42889 | 04.09.2020 14:16 |                           |
| 42890 | 04.09.2020 14:17 | PQ_COST SWEDEN            |
| 42891 | 04.09.2020 14:17 | PQ_COST SWEDEN            |
| 42892 | 04.09.2020 14:17 |                           |
| 42893 | 04.09.2020 14:17 |                           |
| 42894 | 04.09.2020 14:17 | PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM |
| 42895 | 04.09.2020 14:17 | PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM |
+-------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

Example select:

```
SELECT
start_time
FROM table
WHERE
queue <> 'PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM' 
AND seq **IS NEXT HIGHER SEQ-VALUE COMPARED TO** (SELECT seq 
            FROM table 
            WHERE 
            queue = 'PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM'
            AND seq = MIN(seq))
```

Expected result from table for NEXT HIGHER SEQ-VALUE COMPARED TO:
42890

This would be the next higher number where the condition is met, based on the minimum-sequence number and the condition in the sub-select (34962).

How can I find exactly the next higher sequence-number under certain where-conditions?

Is there even an Oracle-SQL-command? By the way: order by is not an option for the scenario I need it.

Comment: Please post the schema of your `cc_case_stat_log` table, and some examples of expected output with their associated table contents as input.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "sequence". It looks like you want to return a single scalar value.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: And an appropriate database tag -- along with readable data.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try ranking function after calculating the time differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
    (
    select min(seq) from table t2
    where t2.seq > t.seq and queue = 'PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM'
    ) as next_seq
FROM table t
WHERE queue <> 'PQ_NEW PRICE REQUEST GMDM';
```